# Console command waiting for input from user

Tags: magento2, cli, command-line

It is possible in PHP to create console command waiting for an input from user like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322371/php-wait-for-input-from-command-line) or like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794030/interactive-shell-using-php). Is there any 'magento-way' or above approaches can be used?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/console-command-magento-2/  or http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112022/correct-supported-way-to-add-cli-commands-to-magento-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento 2 using **symfony** for CLI commands. So symfony is having a all these kind of featurs.

To create CLI comment in magento check [here](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/console-command-magento-2/)

Then in your module console command file eg:

> Inchoo\Console\Console\Command\HelloWorldCommand.php

```
<?php

namespace Inchoo\Console\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion;

Class HelloWorldCommand extends Command
{

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('inchoo:hello_world')->setDescription('Prints hello world.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $question = new ConfirmationQuestion('your question', false);
        $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
        echo $ans = $helper->ask($input, $output, $question);
        if ($ans == 'yes') {
           $output->writeln('Hello World!');
        }else{
            $output->writeln('Noooooooo');
        }
        $output->writeln('Done!');
    }

}
```

**Refer [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/questionhelper.html) for other CLI command like Multiple Choices question.**

Comment: This is a useful proof of concept but DON'T USE OBJECT MANAGER DIRECTLY. Also, don't prefix protected/private entities with underscore.